# Why do I get dropped calls and weak signal with Samsung Galaxy 3 5801 mobile?

Tags: calls, connection-issues, samsung-galaxy-apollo, gprs

Samsung Galaxy 3 5801 phone with android 2.1 OS.

When I enable GPRS I am getting dropped calls and weak signal. When I disable GPRS I find my calls don't drop and the signal much better.

Is it a hardware issue or service provider issue or a software issue? How can I fix it?

Comment: GPRS? Do you mean GPS?

Comment: Perhaps he means GPRS data.

Comment: Poor Battery just last 7-8 hrs.
Severe call drops 
No front camera.

A bad buy for me, I would never rec

Answer (score 2):

It's almost certainly a software issue, I have read forum posts saying that the call gets dropped when apps/accounts try to sync over the data connection.  As a temporary solution you can turn off account sync/background data.  Hopefully it will be fixed in 2.2.

Comment: hi,

Thx a lot for u'r reply, really appreciate u'r prompt response... 
Can i update software 2.1 to 2.2. how can i do that. is it available for Galaxy 3..

Thanks in advance....

joby

Comment: Yes, you can get 2.2 via Kies.  Get it from http://www.samsung.com/in/consumer/mobile-phone/mobile-phone/touch-phone/GT-I5801DKAINU/index.idx?pagetype=prd_detail&tab=support

Comment: I'm excited! My latest Kies download is under progress now.... Please tell me, is 2.2 official upgrade released?

Comment: Yes, Kies will get you the official upgrade.